# Ant var and property scope

Tags: ant

I have a main build script that calls various targets.  One of these targets needs to store a value and another target needs to display it.  Obviously this is not working so I think it may be related to scope.  I've tried var, property, and declaring the property outside of target1.  Since var seems to be mutable, it looks like I need to use it instead, but each time my output is empty.

Main script

```
<antcall target="target1"/>
<antcall target="display"/>
```

In target1:

```
<var name="myVar" value="${anotherVar}"/>
```

In display:

```
<echo>${myVar}</echo>
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need to use <antcall>? Can you use target dependencies instead?

As you suspect, using <antcall> essentially creates a new scope.

Comment: We have a dependency mess right now and were trying to componentize our shared targets to remove any inner dependencies and do some cleanup while were there.

Comment: Often <antcall> is used because of nested <param> tags.

Answer (score 4):

antcall will start the ant target in a new project and will not affect the main project in any way.  Try runtarget from antcontrib to run the targets in the same project.

Comment: +1: Thank you for this hint. With `runtarget` I was able to clean up my build files easlily.

Answer (score 2):

You can call multiple targets with one `antcall` element. These targets will then share a single project instance including the properties defined. To do this specify the targets as nested elements like this:

```
<antcall>
  <target name="target1"/>
  <target name="display"/>
</antcall>
```

Comment: Interesting idea.  I have other target calls in-between these two.  I could add all of them in there, but then I would have the same scope/security problem if I change all of them to runtarget.  But either way its a trade-off.

Comment: This is only supported since Ant 1.6.3, otherwise you'll see: "The <antcall> task doesn't support the nested "target" element."

Comment: this doesn't share properties between the two targets.

Answer (score 2):

Another option I found was the antcallback, and it appears to work.  This limits what is returned to just a particular list of values, which seems inherently safer than opening up the scope of the whole target (as it sets, creates, modifies many var and properties).

```
<antcallback target="target1" return="myVar"/>
<antcall target="display"/>
```

I think all of these are valid solutions, it just depends on what level you want to change the variable scope at.

Answer (score 0):

```
<antcall target="display">
   <param name="param1" value="anything" />
</antcall>
```

put the above code in your target1. I am sure you will be able to access your param1 in display now.